# Start/Stop/Restart OS *inux services using Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Sadly, we don't use node extensively at my work (yet anyway), however, I wanted to write a small "watcher" app in Node that would preform some very basic health checks on the local server and if a problem is detected I want this watcher app to restart the associated service.

For example, I want to check Apache every 5 minutes to ensure HTTP is available. If not, I'd like the app to restart httpd as well as the application server process and send an alert. I just can't find anything on the internets' that discusses restarting OS level services using Node... but with all the posts on "how to daemonize Node" I could have missed something in the clutter.

Any help/direction would be appreciated.

My particular setup:

- OS: Cent OS 6.3
- Node: v0.10.19

Comment: It's very simple... just execute an external process.  http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Is everything in Node this easy?!! :) -- Thanks for the direction. I'll read up on this and see if I can figure out.

Comment: This isn't a Node thing... you would use the same method no matter which technology stack you were using.

Comment: Are you rewriting http://mmonit.com/monit/ ?

Comment: For just practice, doing this is fine. If however you are monitoring vital production severs, the sysadmin in me screams to use one of the mature packages available for this out of the box. Nothing more irritating or possibly disastrous as a bug in a quickly whipped up monitoring application, and in those packages edge cases & obscure bugs are already found & taken care of. Something like `monit` et al.

Comment: @PeterLyons, no, I just need some basic functionality but I'm going to look at Monit now as I guess I could just use this library.

Comment: Yes there are many mature products for this use case both FOSS and commercial. Monit, nagios, pingdom, new relic etc

Answer (score 0):

As [Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362536/brad) pointed out, http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html was indeed the answer.

In short:

```
  var exec = require( 'child_process' ).exec

  exec( 'service httpd stop', function( error, stdout, stderr ){ } );
```

But please read the docs. :)